# Parsing XML with Spark - Facing issues with different approaches need suggestions?

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

I have XML that I'm trying to parse with Spark Code. I have two approach:

1. Using com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlReader
2. Using HiveContext - Make DF and traverse the xml

Any other ways if these please share. I'll share my answers below

Answer (score 0):

Here are the sample code which I used but the problem here is if there is any changes in Schema it'll be always required to change the Code.

```
import Util.XmlFileUtil
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf,SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

object xPathReader extends App{

    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir","C:\\hadoop\\winutils")

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MstarXmlIngestion").setMaster("local[5]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
    val fscXmlPath = "C:\\data\\xml"
    val xmlRddList = XmlFileUtil.withCharset(sc, fscXmlPath, "UTF-8", "book")

    import hiveContext.implicits._

    val xmlDf = xmlRddList.toDF("xml")
    xmlDf.registerTempTable("TEMPTABLE")

    hiveContext.sql("select xpath_string(xml,\"/book/@_id\") as BookId, xpath_string(xml,\"/book/description\") as description, CurrID, Price from TEMPTABLE " +
      "LATERAL VIEW OUTER explode(xpath(xml,\"/book/market/price/text()\")) PRICE_LIST as Price " +
      "LATERAL VIEW OUTER explode(xpath(xml,\"/book/currency/price/text()\")) CurrID_LIST as CurrID").show()
}


Another XmlFileUtil Class

===================================================
import com.databricks.spark.xml.util.XmlFile;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD;

/**
 * Utility class to access private `XmlFile` scala object from spark xml package
 */
public class XmlFileUtil {
    public static RDD<String> withCharset(SparkContext context, String location, String charset, String rowTag) {
        return XmlFile.withCharset(context, location, charset, rowTag);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, we cant use a generic solution for all the XML files.
If your XML file changes, the code will too.

In my code I have used XML source for SparkSQL by databricks
You can find it [here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml)

Comment: Accept that we have to change code as per the schema changes. But if we make use of DF for that then will it works. Definitely we have to make some twists. I'll share my another approach

Answer (score 0):

As said here is the another approach:

```
object XmlSecondApproach extends App{

  System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir","C:\\hadoop\\winutils")

  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Second Approach").setMaster("local[5]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
  val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
  val rawXmlPath = "C:\\data\\xml\\RawXML"

  val objXMLDR = new XmlDataReader

  var rawDf = objXMLDR.getRawXmlDataframe(sc, rawXmlPath, "book")

  rawDf.registerTempTable("tempBookTable")

  rawDf.printSchema()

  hiveContext.udf.register("customFunction",UDFWrappedArrayConverter.checkIfWrappedArray)

  //When we get more than one arrays in a parent node then we need to handle parent repeated node with explode
  hiveContext.sql("SELECT book.currency.price as curPrice, " +    
    "markET.price as mktPrice from tempBookTable " +
    "LATERAL VIEW OUTER explode(book.market) Mrkt_List as markET").show()   
}

//Define another scala class
class XmlDataReader {

  def getRawXmlDataframe(sc:SparkContext,  xmlPath: String, rowTag: String): DataFrame = {

    val xmlRddList = XmlFileUtil.withCharset(sc, xmlPath, "UTF-8", rowTag)
    val xmlReader = new XmlReader()
    val xmlDf = xmlReader.withAttributePrefix(Constant.ATTR_PREFIX).withValueTag(Constant.VALUE_TAG).withRowTag(rowTag.toLowerCase).xmlRdd(hiveContext, xmlRddList)
    return xmlDf
  }
}
```